# Lync Integration with sharepoint hosted apps - Lync API 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, lync, sharepoint-online, lync-2013

I want to integrate lync presence,user profile picture and chat functionality with my sharepoint hosted apps. I have spent hours in searching the way to achieve this however no luck. I would appreciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried adding the Lync client SDK to your project? It's available as a free download, here:

[Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824)

If you tried this and are having problems, please provide the details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Sharepoint 2013 Lync Presence Using jQuery](http://customsp.blogspot.com/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-lync-presence-using.html)

You can show lync presence and profile picture using this jquery plugin. Also using contact card user can initiate the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can render the presence in a SharePoint hosted app, it will not work regarding the presence indicator. Lync checks and modifies the html in the browser, thus changing the presence indicator color by changing of the classes on the html.
Lync will NOT check presence indicators in iframes, so the presence of a person, shown in a iframe, will not be set.